# firefox html login form issues?

Tags: html, firefox

i need help please, i am trying to figure this out but i dont know what the problem is.

Basically i have this login form:

```
<form id="myform" action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">

Email
  <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="john.smith@example.com" />

Password
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="*****" />

<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton"/>

            </form>
```

And it works in all browsers but firefox.

For some reason ive narrowed it down to the image being used for the submit button, because if i use this form below then firefox works fine and logs in but it doesnt with the one above. any ideas whats wrong? Thanks.

```
            <form action="login.php" method="post">

    Email:
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john.smith@example.com" />


    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login &gt;" />


</form>
```

Comment: Error? Does the form submit at all? Does it submit but nothing gets passed? Does it do nothing? Does it do anything?

Comment: no error, its going to login.php because im being redirected to that page but its asking me to login still so not running the login script.

Comment: What are you using to make the login script start? Can you display or echo all of the form variables passed in. I posted a link below that states on an image submit, FF4 only passes in the X/Y position of the image clicked, not the name itself.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/382/firefox-4-change-input-type-image-only-submits-x-and-y-not-name Does this perhaps answer your issue? Are you looking for the submit name for process your request?